# Make GWT app run side by side with a Rest API (Deploy Resteasy in Root)

Tags: java, rest, gwt, servlets, resteasy

When using GWT we use this URL forms:

Debug:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997#hash
```

Compiled:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html#hash
```

I need to be able to access the underlying Rest API.

Which I need to map within the "root"

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/{contentId}
```

However this will sure break the GWT application access, and that it will not be accessible anymore.

How can I make this work together, considering the main requirement to have the Rest API in the root?

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">


    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.guice.modules</param-name>
        <param-value>org.jboss.errai.ui.demo.server.MyModule</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**Edit:**

The idea is that I should be able to do both:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html#hash
```

and

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/abc123
```

That is, to co-exist with the "GWT servlet" since both the GWT servlet and the Rest API "servlet" will be deployed in the same server and same webapp path.

Comment: I dont fully understand what you mean with `break the GWT application access`, 1.- are you deploying your webservices (rest) and your gwt files in the same server? 2.- does your gwt app use other servlets (RPC, RF, etc)? 3.- are your `*.nocache.js` file in a subfolder of your root (/module/*.nocache.js) ?

Comment: Do I need to do a filter for this, I mean to filter the root then see if the request is index.html or something else, problem would be the root API is accepting contentID which could be any string, this could be the reason causing the request for index.html not to be serviced

Comment: I'm thinking of a filter to check whether the request in the root is index.html if not it will forward to the Rest API, something like this

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need to take care of root context in your own servlet. The basic idea is to map YourRoutingServlet to /* path and then handle get/post and other calls by analyzing the request path(gwt or rest) and delegate handling to appropriate servlet.

Depenging on you application specific you can extend e.g. gwt servlet(RemoteServiceServlet) and check request url and if this is a gwt url(with #hash) then just call super method, if not then delegate the req/resp to rest servlet.

This would also mean that you have to have instance of rest servlet in your servlet or you can use servlet redirects(which I would not suggest)